# Vaadin 8 Grid - perform action on changing (row) focus - GridFastNavigation

Tags: java, focus, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

when searching for anything related to a Vaadin grid focus listener or similar, they keep pointing me to the GridFastNavigation add-on... and I tried it...

The only thing I want to do is to perform a simple action (two lines of code - refresh a preview) when the (row) focus in the Grid changes, i.e. when up or down keys are pressed. Nothing editable there, the grid is used only for display.
We extended the grid, and like in the demo project, I initialize the navigation stuff in the constructor of our grid. This is the code I currently have there

```
FastNavigation<M> nav = new FastNavigation<>(this, true, false);
nav.setChangeColumnAfterLastRow(true);

nav.addRowFocusListener(event -> {
    if (event.getRow() >= 0) {
        M model = (M) event.getItem();
        refreshDetailLayout(model);
    }
});
```

This looks very straightforward, but nothing happens, when navigating the grid. I tried debugging, and the only thing I could find out is that the code in the listener doesn't even get executed.

Are there any certain prerequisites for this add-on to work? Are there any known restrictions like other listeners right on the grid (such as ItemClick- or ShortcutListener) interfering with it?

I'm currently at Vaadin 8.4.5 and GridFastNavigation 2.3.5

Comment: I just tested it with the demo application, turned editor of, and commented out adding all other listeners but this one, and it worked for me. I have also item click listener there, and it is not interfering this. Thus I would first like to double check, did you remember to recompile the widgetset?

Comment: OK... I was sure I had done that right... But it seems I had lost track in this huge project where I wanted to integrate this. Looks like I had added the dependency to the wrong pom file (of about 20 - feels like 100 though).
I moved it and compiled through everything (including widgetset) and it works like a charm.
Thanks for pointing me the right way

Comment: Good, I am glad to hear you got it working.